# Programmaticaly define size of SQL columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on an ETL job in Azure Databricks. When I am writing to an Azure DB, the nvarchar columns are created as nvarchar(max).

I am doing the following to write the dataframe to SQL:

```
df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", _get_dw_jdbc_url()) \
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
    .option("dbTable", table_name) \
    .option("tempDir", _get_temp_connection_string()) \
    .option("maxStrLength", 255)\
    .mode(mode) \
    .save()
```

I was hoping the maxStrLength would magically fix the problem, but it is not.

Any solutions on this one? Can I define the schema for the SQL table prior to writing to the database?

Comment: What I would like to do is something similar to what you can do in Scala by using bulkCopyToSqlDB with ColumnMetadata. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#write-data-to-azure-sql-database-or-sql-server-using-bulk-insert

Answer (score 0):

Use pyodbc to create the table before you do the write above. This would mean your mode would have to be append (you haven't shown it in the snippet).

The lengths cannot be determined until the complete soruce data has been read, so Spark cannot calculate these on the fly as it starts writing (usually/ideally) before reading has finished.